# Include Child Record Count in json Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to include a `item_count` field in a json response on Rails. I have a list of `Categories` and each of those records has one or more `Items`.

Here is my current index.json.jbuilder file:

```
json.array! @categories, partial: 'categories/category', as: :category
```

And the _category.json.jbuilder partial

```
json.extract! category, :id, :name, :created_at, :updated_at
json.url category_url(category, format: :json)
```

I want to include `category.item_count` in the response but I'm not exactly sure how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `item_count` to the partial like this:

```
json.item_count category.items.count
```

However, for each category, it will execute an additional query (to get the number of items):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `items` WHERE `items`.`category_id` = ID
```